# Ionic: webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Ionic app seems to have stopped working and I am not able pinpoint the cause. I started again from blank app, but this error persists

Not sure if I am missing setup steps or issue with version mismatch? any pointers would help as I have wasted weeks on this issue

Accepted answers, like -
[WebpackJsonp missing after Ionic 3 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325392/webpackjsonp-missing-after-ionic-3-update) or [Ionic 2: ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988166/ionic-2-referenceerror-webpackjsonp-is-not-defined) have not worked

index.html has

```
<!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

<!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
 It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

<!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
<script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

ionic info -

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
Node              : v9.5.0
npm               : 5.7.1
```

service.worker.js has-

```
// pre-cache our key assets
self.toolbox.precache(
[
 './build/main.js',
 './build/vendor.js',
 './build/main.css',
 './build/polyfills.js',
 'index.html',
 'manifest.json'
]
);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Having the same issue after too.